# which method is best to export google analytics data into my custom dashboard

Tags: php, symfony1, google-analytics

I want to create my custom dashboard for my site where i show all the google analytics data in custom view. but i'm very confused about google api. i'm using **symfony framework** to create this dashboard. so, which code api is most popular and sufficient for me. pleaqse suggest me.

Comment: This should be possible to do with any Framework, or with none at all. Just use what you know best, and like to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Symfony - use the PHP API.

Google Analytics Date Export has a list of client libraries here : http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataLibraries.html

PHP is shown at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use Zend_Gdata_Analytics, it has a cleaner api than GAPI class referenced on gdata libraries page. I've actually wrapped this class around my own to write specific analytic methods like this:

```
  public function getVisitsByDate()
  {
    $query = $this->createQuery() 
      ->addDimension('ga:date')  
      ->addMetric('ga:visits')
      ->setSort('ga:date')
    ;
    return $this->getDataFeed($query);
  }
```

Then I would serialize the results and visualize with Hicharts.js library, but it's really up to you what library to use.

Comment: thanks to answer, but can you give me some tutorial links about use zend_gdata_analytics with symfony

Comment: There isn't anything special about using zend classes with symfony, exept that you need to enable Zend's autoloader. There's an example in the jobeet tutorial on how to do that.